# How to sort a dataframe by column and get the index?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I want to sort a dataframe in R by a column and add the ranking to a new column.

Specifically, I want to rank the `price` column in the `data.frame` below (ascending) for every day. Then, I want to add a column indicating the rank of every hour of the day.

```
library(dplyr)
prices <- data.frame(time = c("2014-07-01 00:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 01:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 02:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 03:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-01 04:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 05:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 06:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 07:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-01 08:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 09:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 10:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 11:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-01 12:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 13:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 14:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 15:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-01 16:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 17:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 18:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 19:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-01 20:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 21:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 22:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 23:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-02 00:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 01:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 02:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 03:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-02 04:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 05:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 06:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 07:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-02 08:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 09:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 10:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 11:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-02 12:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 13:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 14:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 15:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-02 16:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 17:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 18:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 19:00:00 CEST",
                  "2014-07-02 20:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 21:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 22:00:00 CEST","2014-07-02 23:00:00 CEST"),
         price = c(31.75,30.54,30.10,29.32,25.97,26.90,33.59,41.06,40.99,42.44,40.00,39.94,35.69,36.00,36.00,35.17,34.94,35.18,39.00,
                   41.92,40.09,38.87,39.38,36.00,30.26,29.29,29.37,25.15,25.81,27.97,31.63,39.91,39.99,39.61,39.13,40.43,38.41,36.96,
                   36.00,34.95,33.82,36.08,38.59,39.91,39.02,36.90,38.88,32.59))
```

I am using `arange` from `dplyr` for the sorting as follows.

```
prices_sorted <- arrange(df, format(df$time, format="%Y-%m-%d"), real)
```

Is there a 'clean' way to arrive at the following?

```
prices_ranked
                   time price ranking
1  2014-07-01 00:00:00 CEST 31.75       5
2  2014-07-01 01:00:00 CEST 30.54       6
3  2014-07-01 02:00:00 CEST 30.10       4
4  2014-07-01 03:00:00 CEST 29.32       3
5  2014-07-01 04:00:00 CEST 25.97       2
6  2014-07-01 05:00:00 CEST 26.90       1
7  2014-07-01 06:00:00 CEST 33.59       7
8  2014-07-01 07:00:00 CEST 41.06      17
9  2014-07-01 08:00:00 CEST 40.99      16
10 2014-07-01 09:00:00 CEST 42.44      18
11 2014-07-01 10:00:00 CEST 40.00      13
12 2014-07-01 11:00:00 CEST 39.94      14
13 2014-07-01 12:00:00 CEST 35.69      15
14 2014-07-01 13:00:00 CEST 36.00      24
15 2014-07-01 14:00:00 CEST 36.00      22
16 2014-07-01 15:00:00 CEST 35.17      19
17 2014-07-01 16:00:00 CEST 34.94      23
18 2014-07-01 17:00:00 CEST 35.18      12
19 2014-07-01 18:00:00 CEST 39.00      11
20 2014-07-01 19:00:00 CEST 41.92      21
21 2014-07-01 20:00:00 CEST 40.09       9
22 2014-07-01 21:00:00 CEST 38.87       8
23 2014-07-01 22:00:00 CEST 39.38      20
24 2014-07-01 23:00:00 CEST 36.00      10
25 2014-07-02 00:00:00 CEST 30.26       4
26 2014-07-02 01:00:00 CEST 29.29       5
27 2014-07-02 02:00:00 CEST 29.37       6
28 2014-07-02 03:00:00 CEST 25.15       2
29 2014-07-02 04:00:00 CEST 25.81       3
30 2014-07-02 05:00:00 CEST 27.97       1
31 2014-07-02 06:00:00 CEST 31.63       7
32 2014-07-02 07:00:00 CEST 39.91      24
33 2014-07-02 08:00:00 CEST 39.99      17
34 2014-07-02 09:00:00 CEST 39.61      16
35 2014-07-02 10:00:00 CEST 39.13      15
36 2014-07-02 11:00:00 CEST 40.43      18
37 2014-07-02 12:00:00 CEST 38.41      22
38 2014-07-02 13:00:00 CEST 36.96      14
39 2014-07-02 14:00:00 CEST 36.00      13
40 2014-07-02 15:00:00 CEST 34.95      19
41 2014-07-02 16:00:00 CEST 33.82      23
42 2014-07-02 17:00:00 CEST 36.08      21
43 2014-07-02 18:00:00 CEST 38.59      11
44 2014-07-02 19:00:00 CEST 39.91      10
45 2014-07-02 20:00:00 CEST 39.02       8
46 2014-07-02 21:00:00 CEST 36.90      20
47 2014-07-02 22:00:00 CEST 38.88       9
48 2014-07-02 23:00:00 CEST 32.59      12
```

Comment: If you're grouping by day it would be best to include an example that covers more than one day, and the desired result from that

Comment: Good point, I edited the example to include two full days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a little unclear on what order you wanted things in, but is this what you were looking for? Updated to rank by date (I added in some additional data so you could see that)

```
library(data.table)
prices <- data.table(time = c("2014-07-01 00:00:00 CEST", "2014-07-01 01:00:00 CEST", "2014-07-01 02:00:00 CEST","2014-07-01 03:00:00 CEST", "2014-07-01 04:00:00 CEST",
"2015-07-01 00:00:00 CEST", "2015-07-01 01:00:00 CEST", "2015-07-01 02:00:00 CEST","2015-07-01 03:00:00 CEST", "2015-07-01 04:00:00 CEST"),
         price = c(31.75, 30.54, 30.10, 29.32, 25.97,31.75, 30.12, 31.10, 39.32, 25.97))
prices <- prices[,"date" := as.Date(time)]

prices.sorted <- prices[order(time),ranking := rank(price,ties.method='first'), by=date]
```

Comment: Works like a charm @Tchotchke, thanks. Indeed I want to sort per day, I also updated my question to clarify that part. Is there also a way to do the same thing on a `data.frame` (even though  `data.table` might be faster)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
prices %>% arrange(price) %>% mutate(ranking=min_rank(price)) %>% arrange(time)
#                      time price ranking
#1 2014-07-01 00:00:00 CEST 31.75    5
#2 2014-07-01 01:00:00 CEST 30.54    4
#3 2014-07-01 02:00:00 CEST 30.10    3
#4 2014-07-01 03:00:00 CEST 29.32    2
#5 2014-07-01 04:00:00 CEST 25.97    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it uses the base R solution `sort`:

```
 prices %>% mutate(ranking = row_number(sort(price, decreasing = T)))
                      time price ranking
1 2014-07-01 00:00:00 CEST 31.75       5
2 2014-07-01 01:00:00 CEST 30.54       4
3 2014-07-01 02:00:00 CEST 30.10       3
4 2014-07-01 03:00:00 CEST 29.32       2
5 2014-07-01 04:00:00 CEST 25.97       1
```